# NSCoreDataException: CoreData could not fulfill a fault for

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, restkit

I am trying to sync bookmarks in a pdf reader app toward a server. The bookmarks are saved to core data and then synced towards the server.

However, I get an exception when trying to sync to core data at the same time as I sync core data with restkit. The error I get:

```
CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x11940014b <x-coredata://5F7F2CE2-4C88-4D87-9C96-B475DC029FCA/Bookmark/p1125>'
```

The code that is called when clicking the remove button:

```
- (BOOL)removeBookmarkForPage:(NSUInteger)page inBook:(IBBook *)book
{
    __block BOOL isSuccess = NO;

    dispatch_sync(_bookmarkQueue, ^{
        [[[IBCoreDataManager sharedManager] moc] performBlockAndWait:^() {
            NSMutableSet *bookmarks = [_bookmarkCache objectForKey:book.isbn];
            [bookmarks enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                IBBookmark *bookmark = (IBBookmark *)obj;
                if ([bookmark.pageNumber integerValue] == page) {
                    bookmark.action = kAnnotationIsRemovedKey;
                }
            }];

            [_bookmarkCache setObject:bookmarks forKey:book.isbn];
        }];
    });

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IBBookmarksDidChangeNotification object:self];

    return isSuccess;
}
```

The row of `bookmark.action = kAnnotationIsRemovedKey;` is the one casting the exception.

The exception is only cast when a sync is occurring (the method below is called). When it's syncing, it saves the cache to coredata:

```
- (BOOL)saveAllBookmarksToCoreDataForBook:(IBBook *)book withError:(NSError **)error
{
    __block BOOL isSuccess = YES;

    dispatch_sync(_bookmarkQueue, ^{
        [[[IBCoreDataManager sharedManager] moc] performBlockAndWait:^() {
            NSMutableSet *bookmarksInCache = [_bookmarkCache objectForKey:book.isbn];
            NSMutableSet *annotations = [NSMutableSet set];
            if (bookmarksInCache) {
                [book.userAnnotations enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                    if (![obj isKindOfClass:[IBBookmark class]]) {
                        [annotations addObject:obj];
                    }
                }];
                [annotations unionSet:bookmarksInCache];
                book.userAnnotations = annotations;
            }

            NSError *coreDataError;
            [[IBCoreDataManager sharedManager] saveToPersistantStoreWithError:&coreDataError];
            if (coreDataError) {
                isSuccess = NO;
                *error = coreDataError;
            }
        }];
    });

    return isSuccess;
}

@end
```

`_bookmarkQueue` is defined as:

```
_bookmarkQueue = dispatch_queue_create([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myAppName.%@", self] UTF8String], DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

The `_moc` is defined as:

```
_moc = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
```

Any ideas on how to solve?

**Update:**

I also get this error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'userAnnotations' between objects in different contexts (source = <IBBook: 0x10045eb90> (entity: Book; id: 0x240004b <x-coredata://76F2C086-D7DE-4210-B0C1-AA49DC5802D3/Book/p9> ;

destination = <IBBookmark: 0x102fa10b0> (entity: Bookmark; id: 0x22a40014b <x-coredata://76F2C086-D7DE-4210-B0C1-AA49DC5802D3/Bookmark/p2217> ; data: <fault>))'
```

on the row of `book.userAnnotations = annotations;` in ?`saveAllBooksmarksToCoreDataForBook:withError:`

Comment: Give details of your classes, Core Data stack, how you're using RestKit. Is RestKit deleting orphaned items for you? What threads are you using? How many MOCs do you have and how are they specified?

Comment: "The exception is only cast when a sync is occurring" What's the number of concurrent tasks in `_bookmarkQueue`? When > 1 you are using the same managed object context in different threads, since the queue will have multiple threads (to be able to perform concurrent operations), and you are using the same managed object context. Managed object contexts are not thread safe.

Comment: I'm quite new to Core Data. How do I check concurrent tasks in _bookmarkQueue? Added definition of _moc. I am never deleting any objects in CoreData. Only setting the `action` string to "deleted" string. This so I can mark them as deleted on the server.

Comment: You only posted a part of the `dispatch_queue_create` statement. What's the second parameter? `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` or `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT`?

Comment: Other question: Is the method `removeBookmarkForPage:inBook:` updating the moc without saving it (i don't see any saveContext statements)?

Comment: Oh sorry, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL

Comment: No `removeBookmarkForPage:inBook:` does only save the bookmark to a `NSMutableDictionary`. `saveAllBookmarksToCoreDataForBook:inBook:` does the saving to Core Data.

Comment: Just reading your update. So, it looks like you DO have multiple contexts(!). You are adding an annotation which exists in context A to a relationship `IBBook.userAnnotations` in context B. You cannot share managed objects between different managed object contexts. So the annotation has to be fetched in the same context as your IBBook object. Just another thought: Since the message proved you do have multiple contexts you should find out about them. You should know where your contexts are created/managed, and when to use which context, and also initiate merge actions when needed.